# How call a javascript function from another javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a main html file called default.html with two javascript files default.js and backend.js.

The two javascript files are added as follow in the main html

```
<script src="assets/js/backend.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/default.js"></script>
```

the default.js contains this setup

```
 startUp()
  
eel.expose(startUp);
function startUp(){
    
 showNextPage() // this work and shows the next page
    
}

function showNextPage(){

 console.log("show next page")
  window.location = 'next.html'
}
```

I then tried to call default.js function showNextPage() from backend.js, it only shows the console.log message but does not change the page.

everything works fine when i call showNextPage within default.js. I've tried many methods but it all seem like it's not allowing me to change the page from backend.js.
How can I fix this and call page change from backend.js?

I have tried
window.location.href = "next.html"

window.location.replace = ("next.html")

and other variations. For reason unknown, everything works except changing of pages from backend.js

Comment: What does the console say? Any errors?

Comment: do you mean the two js are BOTH having the showNextPage() function ?

Comment: no, the function is in default.js only

Comment: Did you try the second part of my answer?

Comment: Javascript is loaded sequentially. So showNextPage will be undefined if you load backend.js first. Is it possible switch the script tags around.

Comment: @GraemeNiedermayer I tried both ways but still no change